# Unable to debug typescript using VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

New to typescript. Trying to setup VSCode for debugging TypeScript.
I have followed https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-debugging page and other setup topics such as this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zdBk6wisxc

I tried `ts-ndoe` as well.

No matter. The VSCode debugger only understands the generated `javascript` code, not the original `typescript` code.

Have anyone succeeded in ever setting up VSCode to debug `TypeScript` properly, not the generated `javascript` code? If so, what are the steps?

Answer (score 0):

Try launching a “Debug Terminal” in VSCode and running your script using ts-node inside that terminal. I believe VSCode will attempt to auto-attach the debugger to the process.